# How can I pass a variable to all of my views? (Django)

Tags: django

I need to use the same object in all of my views. Is there a better way to get it in the template than repeating myself in each view. e.g., I need to get `Myobj.objects.all()` for all of my views.

Thanks

Comment: In your views, or in your templates?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [context processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) are what you're looking for here.